# ¿ Como dividir campos de una tabla con SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

tengo una entidad o tabla de base de datos con registros como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy consiente que la entidad necesita normalización de base de datos pero por el momento solo tengo permisos de lectura y no se me permite hacer modificaciones de tal tipo, lo cual seria obviamente lo mejor.

Lo que quiero es hacer una consulta (Query) que me permita eliminar la redundancia que hay en esos registros de tal forma que pueda obtener un registro único por cada CURSO con tres nuevos campos que representen el numero del periodo y su CALIFICACIÓN. Obteniendo un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/135915/edit) especificando mediante una etiqueta el manejador de Base de datos que usas: MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, Postresql... Es más importante que la etiqueta `query` por ejemplo, a fin de aportar una solución específica.

Comment: Hay varias alternativas. Pregunta, ¿Siempre son 3 periodos?

Comment: @A.Cedano Es base de datos Oracle 12g

Comment: @manix Si, siempre son tres periodos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy muy familiarizado con oracle y su sintaxis para [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html). Pero este código resuelve:

```
create table calificacion(
  codigo integer,
  curso varchar(32), 
  periodo integer,
  calificacion decimal(10,2));

insert into calificacion values(1, 'matematica', 1, 3.1);
insert into calificacion values(1, 'matematica', 2, 5);
insert into calificacion values(1, 'matematica', 3, 0);
insert into calificacion values(2, 'inglés', 1, 4.4);
insert into calificacion values(2, 'inglés', 2, 3.1);
insert into calificacion values(2, 'inglés', 3, 3.3);
```

Y la siguiente consulta te daría el resultado deseado

```
select
codigo,
curso,
sum(case when periodo = 1 then calificacion else 0 end) as Periodo1,
sum(case when periodo = 2 then calificacion else 0 end) as Periodo2,
sum(case when periodo = 3 then calificacion else 0 end) as Periodo3
from calificacion
group by codigo, curso
order by codigo
```

Te dejo un [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b0b2/2) con el código anterior.

Comment: Fantástica solución, vale también para mysql. Por cierto, si en vez de SUM utilizas MAX puede servir también para texto. Por ejemplo notas tipo A, B, C.